# Переназначение BackButton

Tags: android

Можем ли мы переназначить кнопку Back? Иначе говоря, не закрывать активити при нажатии на нее, а выполнять другое действие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Можем](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html). Конкретно так

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Выполняем какое-либо другое действие, отличное от заданного по умолчанию
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

либо (начиная с 2.0)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Делаем что-то нужное для нас
    return;
}
```

Comment: Так неработает, мой код выполняется но к тому же активити завершается(

Comment: Работает! Для проверки создайте в Eclipse Android-проект по умолчанию (типа HelloWorld) и добавьте в главную активность строки


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.show();
     
        return;
    }

По клику появляется уведомление, но окно не закрывается.